# Approach to obfuscate an embedded dll in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation, embedded-resource

I have a WPF application whose output is a.exe. This application is dependent on an external b.dll (whose source code I have access to).

**Requirements:**

1. The output should only be a.exe which should contain the dll. I don't want to provide my users with a separate dll (if it can be avoided)
2. I should be able to obfuscate the code. (I don't want anyone to be able to modify it).

**Approaches tried:**

1. I embedded b.dll inside a.exe, it worked. But I was not able to obfuscate the exe as it gave an error that it was unable to find b.dll.
2. I obfuscated a.exe and b.dll but it did not work. It was unable to find b.dll.

**Alternate approach :**

Is there any way that I can perhaps add the spruce code of b.dll to my project and have the dll be compiled to the exe itself rather than a separate dll.

Is it possible to make this alternate approach work or are there any other ways ?

If nothing works, I know that I can compile a and b separately, obfuscate a and provide b as a separate file (what I'm trying to avoid).

Apologies for the formatting issues, if any, I'm using the android app. Let me know if you need any details.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with Eazfuscator.Net in the past.

http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net

To run it from the command line enter the following command:

```
Eazfuscator.Net.exe -n a.exe b.dll
```

It will combine the two files into a single exe. The main program will be able to access the dll.

You can even set up Visual Studio so that the command line above runs as a post compile event.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly embedding may seem quite confusing, so here is how it's usually done:

1. The dependencies are obfuscated if needed.
2. The target assembly is obfuscated. At this point, the obfuscator is also instructed to embed certain dependencies as a part of obfuscation process.
3. As a result, the embedded assemblies are stored as a resource of the target assembly.
4. In order to load dependencies at runtime, obfuscators usually install a handler for `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event that is raised by CLR when it fails to resolve an assembly automatically.
5. The handler extracts and loads an embedded assembly from the resource.

That's it. A good obfuscation tool allows achieving that quite easily. I don't see why it wouldn't work in the case with WPF application. If there are problems, I would recommend contacting product support.

Another option is *assembly merging*. Unlike embedded, the merged assemblies become an inseparable part of the target assembly code. For this reason, the assembly merging often helps to achieve a better obfuscation coverage and application startup time comparing to embedding. Although it may look a better option, merging may sometimes break the application functionality.